# ¿Cómo crear un método que me devuelva dos Listas distintas de Objetos?

Tags: c#, lista

Tal como dice la pregunta, mi objetivo es poder crear un método que tome como parámetros la ruta de 2 archivos, y devolver ambos archivos en Listas separadas.

Estuve ya hablando con los compañeros de SO por el chat y me habían dicho de crear una Tupla.
**CODIGO:**

```
(List <Objeto1> Lista1, List<Objeto2> Lista2) Metodo (List<Objeto1> l1, List<Objeto2> l2){
return(l1,l2);
}
```

Algo como eso me habían dicho pero mi version de VS2017 no acepta tuplas por lo tanto esa posibilidad quedo nula.

Otro consejo que me dieron era hacer un Struct con ambas Listas

```
public struct Book  
{  
    List<Objeto1> L1;
    List<Objeto2> L2;
}
```

Pero luego no se como implementarla en un metodo y realizar las operaciones dentro.

Tampoco sé que tipo de método tiene que ser (tipo me refiero void, int, string, etc). Si me pueden dar una mano.

Si hay alguna otra manera de las de además expuestas anteriormente bienvenida sea. Estoy totalmente trabado.

Gracias.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> mi version de VS2017 no acepta tuplas por lo tanto esa posibilidad quedo nula.

Si tienes VS2017, sin importar la versión que tengas, entonces puedes usar la nueva sintaxis para las tuplas. Y, en efecto, parece que esto sería lo más conveniente para tu caso.

#### Cómo agregar soporte para la nueva sintaxis con tuples

Para poder usar los nuevos tuples, necesitas:

1. Visual Studio 2017
2. Tu proyecto debe estar configurado para C#7 o mayor. Los proyectos en VS2017 están configurados correctamente por defecto.
3. Necesitas que tu proyecto tenga acceso a la clase [`System.ValueTuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.valuetuple(v=vs.110).aspx). Para esto, tienes 2 opciones:

   a. Configurar tu proyecto para que use .NET 4.7 o mayor. Según la versión de Windows 10 que tengas, deberías poder instalar .NET 4.7+ si no lo tienes. Una forma de instalarlo es usando el *Visual Studio Installer*.

   b. Si usar .NET 4.7+ no es una opción, puedes usar [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/) para agregar manualmente [`System.ValueTuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.valuetuple(v=vs.110).aspx) a tu proyecto.

#### ¿Cómo crear un método que me devuelva dos Listas distintas de Objetos?

Entiendo que deseas un método que acepta 2 rutas de archivos y que devuelve 2 listas de objectos distintos. Usar tuples es conveniente para esto:

```
(List<Objeto1> lista1, List<Objeto2> lista2) MiMetodo(string ruta1, string ruta2)
{
    List<Objeto1> lista1 = // transformación de ruta1 a lista1
    List<Objeto2> lista2 = // transformación de ruta2 a lista2

    return (lista1, lista2);
}
```

Luego, para ejecutar el método y obtener los resultados, la sintaxis es:

```
(List<Objeto1> lista1, List<Objeto2> lista2) = MiMetodo("ruta1", "ruta2");
```

... o más compacto con el uso de `var`:

```
var (lista1, lista2) = MiMetodo("ruta1", "ruta2");
```

Comment: Hola sstan, gracias por tu respuesta. Ya agregue la libreria tuplas y anda perfecto. Ahora al implementar las tuplas recibo un error en la devolución de la lista en el Metodo:
            `(List<Cliente> lista1, List<Consumo> lista2) = CargarLista("rutaClientes", "rutaConsumos");`

Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, metodo o propiedad no estático. Program.Cargarlista(string,string). No se como crear una instancia de una tupla con el metodo tendrai que agregarle `static`. por lo que tengo entendido...

Comment: suena a que estás tratando de llamar el método `CargarLista` desde un método `static`. Probablemente es solo cuestión de definir tu método `CargarLista` como `static` también.

Comment: Si le agrego `static` al metodo `CargarLista` no me admite retornar objetos (lista1 y lista2). No hay ningún otro error en la estructura del programa.

Comment: No suena que pusistes el `static` en el lugar correcto. En la definición del método, debería ser algo como `static (List<Cliente> lista1, List<Consumo> lista2) CargarLista(string ruta1, string ruta2) ...`

Comment: Tienes razon, yo había puesto el `static` antes del CargarLista. Error mío. Todo claro. Gracias nuevamente. Un saludo!. Dejo tu respuesta marcada.

Answer (score 2):

Para utilizar la estructura el método debería devolver el tipo de la estructura, en tu caso `Book`:

```
public struct Book
{
    public List<Objeto1> L1;
    public List<Objeto2> L2;
}

public Book Metodo()
{
    var result = new Book
    {
        L1 = new List<Objeto1>(),
        L2 = new List<Objeto2>()
    };

    return result;
}
```

Sin embargo las estructuras en C# sirven para crear nuevos tipos por valor y deberían usarse únicamente para elementos que están compuestos por un número reducido de valores de otros tipos por valor.

Para elementos más complejos como el que quieres definir deberías definir una clase:

```
public class Conjunto
{
    public List<Objeto1> L1 { get; set; }
    public List<Objeto2> L2 { get; set; }
}

public Conjunto Metodo()
{
    var result = new Conjunto
    {
        L1 = new List<Objeto1>(),
        L2 = new List<Objeto2>()
    };
    return result;
}
```

De todas formas, para el caso que planteas, lo más sencillo sería crear un método con parámetros de salida. Estos parámetros se decoran con el modificador `out` lo que no sólo hace que se pasen por referencia, si no que además hace que no sea necesario inicializar las variables.

```
public void Metodo(out List<Objeto1> l1, out List<Objeto2> l2)
{
    l1=new List<Objeto1>();
    l2=new List<Objeto2>();
}
```

De esta forma simplemente habría que pasar como parámetro del método las variables en las que se desea el resultado:

```
List<Objeto1> lista1;
List<Objeto2> lista2;
Metodo(out lista1, out lista2);
```

Las variables `lista1` y `lista2` tendrían el resultado del método.

Comment: Gracias por toda la explicacion, te hago una consulta y para que tome como parametro la ruta del archivo y me devuelva las listas sería ?
`public static void Metodo(string ruta1, stringruta2)` O debo usar la ruta del archivo dentro del metodo para devolver la Lista ?

Comment: Sería algo así: `public void Metodo(string path, out List<Objeto1> l1, out List<Objeto2> l2)`. Un parámetro de entrada y dos de salida.

Comment: Me quedo:  `public void Metodo(string ruta1, string ruta2, out List<Objeto1> lista1, out List<Objeto2> lista2)
        { OPERACIONES ... }`
Ahora bien, para llamar a la funcion: Utilice
`Metodo(ruta1,ruta2,out lista1, out lista2)` y recibo un error que dice que LISTA 1 y LISTA 2 no están en el contexto actual me falto algun indicador ?

Comment: Las variables que pasas al método tienen que estar definidas previamente. Fíjate en mi último ejemplo: defino las variables y luego las paso como parámetros en la llamada al método. Quizás lo veas más claro si utilizas nombres diferentes en la definición del método y en las llamadas.

Si la definición es: `public void Metodo(string ruta1, string ruta2, out List<Objeto1> lista1, out List<Objeto2> lista2)`, la llamada podría ser: `Metodo(path1, path2, out objetos1, out objetos2)`. En el momento de hacer la llamada `path1`, `path2`, `objetos1` y `objetos2` deben estar definidos.